# Check if list cell contains value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Having a dataframe like this:

```
  month  transactions_ids 
0     1         [0, 5, 1]        
1     2            [7, 4]    
2     3    [8, 10, 9, 11]     
3     6               [2]                  
4     9               [3]
```

For a given **transaction_id**, I would like to get the **month** when it took place. **Notice that a transaction_id can only be related to one single month**.

So for example, given **transaction_id = 4**, the **month** would be 2.

I know this can be done in a loop by looking month by month if the **transactions_ids** related contain the given **transaction_id**, but I'm wondering if there is any way more efficient than that.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way in my opinion is to `explode` your data frame and **avoid having python lists in your cells**.

```
df = df.explode('transaction_ids')
```

which outputs

```
   month transactions_ids
0      1                0
0      1                5
0      1                1
1      2                7
1      2                4
2      3                8
2      3               10
2      3                9
2      3               11
3      6                2
4      9                3
```

Then, simply

```
id_to_find = 1 # example
df.loc[df.transactions_ids == id_to_find, 'month']
```

---

P.S: be aware of the duplicated indexes that `explode` outputs. In general, it is better to do `explode(...).reset_index(drop=True)` for most cases to avoid unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` string [methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#string-methods) to find the id in the "list" (it's really just a string as far as `pandas` is concerned when read in using `StringIO`):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 

data = StringIO("""
 month  transactions_ids 
1                [0,5,1]        
2                  [7,4]    
3            [8,10,9,11]     
6                    [2]                  
9                    [3] 
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

df.loc[df['transactions_ids'].str.contains('4'), 'month']
```

In case your `transactions_ids` are real lists, then you can use `map` to check for membership:

```
df['transactions_ids'].map(lambda x: 3 in x)
```